# How to create Custom Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I need to create custom broadcast receiver which will show me about any PHONE_STATE event occurred.

Comment: Do you want to capture incoming Phone-calls and interrupt your broadcast? Or is there something else you want to do? Do you have a Use Case to rely on?

Comment: yes you are right.
When State of Phone changes then i should be able to interrupt Broadcast, Broadcast reciever should display appropiate message like incoming phone etc..Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest you should define the following:

```
<receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The sample receiver class:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    TelephonyManager telManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    switch(telManager.getCallState()) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
      //do something
    }
}
```

}